# How do I uncenter my tasbar icons in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, taskbar

For whatever reason all my icons are now centered in the taskbar on Windows 8.1. How do I get it to be left aligned again?

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the issue for us? You won't be able to upload it directly to SuperUser yet, so please upload it at http://imgur.com and then edit your post/comment with the link. Thank you.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/WDRjy0g.png

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you: `1.` use a different user account, `2.` [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-8), or `3.` [perform a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the icons ended up like this without the use of any third party applications, this should sort it out for you.

Right click on a blank area of the taskbar and look in the *Toolbars* sub-menu. Uncheck (by left clicking) everything in there so that it looks like this:

[image: Windows 8.1 Taskbar Context menu, Toolbars]

.n.b. if multiple items are checked, you will need to go through this process for each item, as clicking on one will close the menu.

Comment: That didn't change anything, and I do have DisplayFusion, but that hasn't been touched in a while so it couldn't be the culprit to this recent issue.

Comment: I notice DisplayFusion added the ability to center taskbar icons a while (two years) back. Might pay just to double check that it wasn't accidentally turned on?

Comment: I found what you are talking about, but I don't even have those options. http://i.imgur.com/cy4mkkY.png

Answer (score 0):

Create a new folder on your desktop and name it Dummy Folder. Right click on taskbar and create new toolbar of dummy folder on your taskbar. Now you can drag the dummy toolbar to place your ican wherever you want. I you want more help go to [How to Center Icons on Windows 8 Taskbar – Tips](http://www.howto-connect.com/center-icons-on-windows-8-taskbar-tips/)